# Android putExtra mystery

Tags: android

[image]

The question above is in image I've just uploaded because Stackoverflow's

editor keeps complaining it was not properly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

you used the same key (`year`) to store `day` and `year` in your `CalendarView` . That's why, when you look for the key `day` it returns `null` (default value)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know why I have it unchecked. Thank you!

Comment: How can I accept an answer? I can't locate a button to have this question tagged as answered.

Comment: Just click on the grayish check mark under the arrows

Answer (score 2):

You problem is in CalendarView, you should write

```
i.putExtra("day",day);
```

instead of

```
i.putExtra("year",day);
```

Comment: Oh my god. I've fooled myself into the foolish thought I did nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

check you putextra() you are using "year" key for year and day

Comment: Sorry about my mistake. I feel so shamed ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
i.putExtra("year", year);
i.putExtra("month", month);
i.putExtra("year", day);
```

to

```
i.putExtra("year", year);
i.putExtra("month", month);
i.putExtra("day", day);
```

Notice how the last `putExtra`'s 1st parameter is different.

Comment: I've been all day long doing coding and feel wasted... That's why I failed to see that. ^^

Comment: Haha! It happens to everyone! Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
i.putExtra("year",day);
```

to

```
i.putExtra("day",day);
```

Comment: Oh I did. I made a tiny mistake that is burning me.^^